# Additional receptacles on 20 amp service using quick holes on back

Tags: electrical

Garage with yellow 12-2 + G wire and 20 AMP breaker. I am adding receptacles. Hubbell has a 20 amp commercial receptacle that will take the 12-2 wire through the holes on the back. I note that these are not blade connectors, there are clamps in the holes operated by the screw on the side. I have read that you should not use the quick connect holes with 12-2 thus my question: Are the Hubbell 20A receptacles okay to use 12-2 in these clamped connector holes (on the back)? Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 6):

That type of outlet is what we call screw-and-clamp (or *I* stubbornly call it screw-*to*-clamp).  [Here's a great page](https://www.handymanhowto.com/electrical-outlets-side-wire-versus-back-wire/) comparing the two.

There is nothing wrong with screw-and-clamp. The only caveat I have from the rare times I've dealt with them, is set your torque correctly. Undertorquing will make the wire(s) pop right out when you shove it into the box.

Using the word "quick" to describe screw-and-clamp is something I strongly discourage, because the trade name for *that other thing* is "Quick-Wire".

(For some reason, manufacturers are reluctant to use our preferred pejorative, **backstab**, for the *jab-and-forget-until-half-the-circuit-goes-dead-for-no-reason* types).

In the early days, UL approved backstab connections which were dual-rated for #14 and #12 wire. But these had problems and they were forced to backpedal from that, because the cheap springs (4 for 50 cents) didn't have the range to grip both wires properly.  (also, accepting #12 copper also meant #12 aluminum could fit, and #12 aluminum is legal in 15A circuits, but that copper-only termination couldn't support it.  This is made worse by copper-clad aluminum being out there, forcing you to look at the wire *end* to determine type).

One time I was running a dehumidifier and the plug felt *warm*.  That shouldn't be.  The socket was warm*er*. So I popped it open and found a #12 stranded wire shoved into the backstab. 1/3 of the strands just splayed all over the place.   **Stranded wire is a *great* application for screw-and-clamp**, because it helps unraveling to super-twist the wires, and that's a lot easier to do on a straight wire than a shepherd's hook.

Answer (score 4):

Those connections are acceptable, better than stab-backs, but many electricians still feel it is better to pigtail the  wire with twist on wire connectors. I find it is easier to push a receptacle into a j-box when less wires are directly connected to the receptacle. There are situations not relevant to 12-2 like Multiwire Branch Circuits (multiple hots using the same neutral) that you should not use the clamps.

Please be aware modifications to any circuit require the modifications be installed to current code (not the code when garage was built), and the current edition of the NEC requires GFCI protection on all 125v 15 and 20 amp receptacles in a residential garage.

Comment: And now current 2020 requires GFCI on 250v rated receptacle circuits too!